# Stopping car break in

Tags: repair

My ex boyfriend keeps picking my car lock while I'm at work. I work at a strip club and he comes in during the night, unlocks the door so anyone can climb in the car. Since it can happen anytime the police/club guards don't seem able to stop it. How do I stop this from happening?

Car is a 2018 Mercedes c300

Comment: Is this a [Life Hack](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions) question? Find somewhere else to park it where he won't know. Or get a court order forbidding him to go anywhere near you, your home, or your place of work.

Comment: I already have a court order

Comment: Then perhaps you need to pay a PI to photograph him in the act and follow it up.

Comment: Are you sure he is picking the locks or does he have a spare key?

Comment: Is it that easy to pick the lock of late model Merc? If that or using a jimmy that would be *forced entry*?

Comment: I would highly suggest you do two things: first, Uber to work; second, if you can't do that, hire one of the bouncers at the strip club to watch your car and when whomever "does their thing", give them a beat... er ... <cough><cough> stern talking to. As far as your vehicle, you can always have an aftermarket alarm put on your vehicle which would be quite obnoxious when someone enters it without your permission. I'm wondering if your ex had a spare set of keys made for it, just for this eventuality. If so, you could have it rekeyed. I only have ideas and not solutions for you, unfortunately.

Comment: @weather https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UbZlaN-2N5k&t=6s

Comment: Are you saying a 2018 Merc has a *keyhole*??

Comment: @WeatherVane If it doesn't have a visible keyhole, there is hidden one for legitimate use of the valet key (for valet parking but keeping your valuables locked up in the trunk) and the reserve key (which only opens the doors but won't start the engine, for use in case you lock your keys inside the car). The "ex BF" may have "borrowed" the valet key before he became "ex".